# Makefile subdirectory recursive

Tags: c++, c, recursion, makefile, subdirectory

I have a problem with makefile for a project with subdir.
The project dir tree is the follow:

```
project
├── Makefile
├── main.cpp
|
├── lib1
│   ├── lib1.cpp
│   ├── lib1.h
│   └── Makefile
|
├── lib2
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── lib2_1.cpp
│   ├── lib2_1.h
|   ├── lib2_2.cpp
│   └── lib2_2.h
| 
├── lib3
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── lib3.cpp
│   └── lib3.h
```

The makefile of each subdir(lib1, lib2...) is like this:

```
SRC_DIR = ./
BUILD_DIR = ./obj/

DEPS = lib1.o

all: $(BUILD_DIR)$(DEPS)

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)%.h
     mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
     g++ --std=c++11 $< -c -o $@

clean:
     rm -fr $(BUILD_DIR)
```

My problem is: How do I create the make file that is located in the project directory, or the makefile "root"? 
I can't create a makefile that executes the makefiles in subdirectories recursively, and which links all object files in the obj folder of each subdir.

Can you help me? Please

Comment: Just a comment which won't solve your problem. Or maybe it will? ;) IMHO, each subdir should have an archive/so target, not a lib1.o target.

Comment: Why each subdir should have an so target?

Comment: archive/so, pick one.  I don't know what you're trying to build, but your directories are named lib[123], so I assume that you're building libraries.

Comment: yes, I can build them as .so files, but with the "root" makefile change something if I create .so files?

Comment: You shouldn't create shared libraries.  That will make your program very complex because you'll have to ship the .so's with your program, make sure your program can find them at runtime, etc.  You can use static libraries (.a's, or archives): that's the same as using .o's.

Comment: Read [recursive make considered harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf). Consider perhaps using [omake](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/omake.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SUBDIRS = lib1 lib2 lib3

main: main.cpp $(SUBDIRS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(wildcard $(addsuffix /obj/*.o,$(SUBDIRS))) $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Good thing about this: it will work properly with `make -jN` for parallel builds, and you can run `make lib1` etc. if you just want to build one subdirectory.

Bad thing about this: it will re-link the `main` program every time you run `make`, even if nothing changed.

If you want to avoid the bad thing, you'll probably want to consider using non-recursive makefiles which will require rewriting your makefiles somewhat.

If you're willing to create a single static library for each subdirectory, named after the directory (so, `liblib1.a` etc.) instead of linking all the object files themselves you can probably make it work with recursive makefiles.  The trick is that the root makefile has to be able to infer, or compute, the names of the libraries by itself.  It can't use `wildcard` etc. to find them.